# How do I turn off lens correction in Lightroom 3?

Tags: lightroom-3, performance, lens-correction

I'm trying to improve Lightroom performance on my Mac and have read that turning off Lens Correction can help the "Loading" times in the develop module.

I really don't care about lens correction and shoot "lomo", so how do I turn off this feature in Lightroom 3?

Comment: Lens Correction shouldn't default to being 'on' for your images, unless you have saved a preset that includes Lens Correction On, and you have either applied that preset automatically on import, or subsequently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When in Develop, there is a Lens Correction panel. Within this panel you can turn profile lens correction on or off using the Enable Profile Corrections checkbox

Answer (score 3):

Lens correction is off by default - you have to check a box to turn it on for an image, or set of images. This is in the **Develop** view, under the **Lens Corrections** panel. The **Enable Profile Corrections** is the toggle.